# Get string inbetween two different characters at nth position

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet containing image files in a column as such. I need to grab the product sku in the file names.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MocUk.png)

Example: "Img_Brand_AA_2021_202020-RD-Mens-Pant-RED-720p_Studio_1849.png"

The product SKU in the above example is: "202020-RD"

I need a formula to grab that product SKU. I've tried the following formula but it only spits out "2020" and I can't get it to grab the SKU.

```
=MID(E2, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,"_",CHAR(1),4))+1, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,"-",CHAR(1),3)) - FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)
```

One thing to note is the Product SKU can be longer than 6 characters.

Thanks!

I've tried the following formula but it only spits out "2020" and I can't get it to grab the SKU.

```
=MID(E2, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,"_",CHAR(1),4))+1, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,"-",CHAR(1),3)) - FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E2,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no Excel version constraints as per tag listed in the question. You can try the following:

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A1,"-",2),"_",-1)
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

Comment: Wow, it really was that simple...thank you!